# php session and other variable bug, it is normal?

Tags: php, session, variables

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["somevariable"] = "blablabla";
print $_SESSION["somevariable"]."<br>";
$somevariable = "some bug";
print $_SESSION["somevariable"]."<br>"; 

output:
blablabla
some bug
```

I creata some session variable ($_session["data"]) and then i create some tipical variable ($data) then $_session variable are overwrite. 
Our server php version is 5.2.5,Zend Engine v2.2.0
Sorry for my english, thanks for help

Comment: you have 3 options 1. set `register_globals` off, 2. if you cannot then change server or 3. later get into a lot of trouble.

Comment: our server has been updated witch windows 2008 R2.. in future, then i configure apache/php server and set register global off, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check on here <kbd>**[codeviper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rFZj7l)**</kbd>

You can change or update session value anytime like normal variable value change but in this case you can not because its prevent you result is override. the reason behind [Global php variable securrity ON](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)`.

e.g. `$_SESSION['item']` is the same as `$item`

You can set on modify `php.ini` file:

```
session.bug_compat_42 = On
```

modify to:

```
session.bug_compat_42 = Off
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: u welcome... i helpfull to you but still someone give me minus rating. anywhere... :)

Answer (score 2):

You have [register globals turned on](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php). This causes the declaration of `$somevariable` to overwrite the `$_SESSION['somevariable']` since they point to the same place.

You should turn this off as it is deprecated and can cause issues like you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

[About superglobals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). Exactly this line:

```
If the deprecated register_globals directive is set to on then the variables 
within will also be made available in the global scope of the script. 
For example, $_POST['foo'] would also exist as $foo.
```

Answer (score -2):

you are over writing the data to the variable,session will remain untill constant in a  page untill it is over writted forcefully by something.